# Android Developer Console, Change the default Language

Tags: android, google-play

I published application through Android developer console with default language as Arabic.

Now, i want to make it default language as English.
How can i do it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Default language for in-app products is inherited from application's default language as it is defined in *Developer Console*.

Open your application in *Developer Console*, choose *Store Listing* and select the language you want to default. Then press on *Manage translations* selector. Choose *Change default language* option and confirm selection. Once done, all your in-app products will inherit new default language.

Answer (score 2):

As you have only one language as Arabic then you have to add english by going to play console -> your application -> store presence -> store listing from menu and select manage translation dropdown menu, then you will see two option, here you have to click on Add your own translation text, then language selection dialog will open,

[image]

here you can add english from list of languages. Now again click on Manage translation menu and click on change default language,

[image]

here you have to click on english and press ok. now you can see your default language is now changed to english, after you can submit update to reflect changes.